# How to read List of Strings in spring application.yml file into Immutables object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, immutables-library, configurationproperties

Here's a sample `application.yml` file

```
myapp:
  resource:
    teststring: "string"
    testlist:
      - "apple"
      - "banana"
```

Here's my immutables configuration class

```
import org.immutables.value.Value.Immutable;
import org.immutables.value.Value.Modifiable;

@Immutable
@Modifiable
public abstract class ResourceConfiguration {

  public abstract String teststring();

  public abstract List<String> testlist();

}
```

Here's my top-level configuration class

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class MyAppConfiguration {

  private final ImmutableResourceConfiguration resource;

  public MyAppConfiguration(ImmutableResourceConfiguration resource) {
    this.resource = resource.toImmutable();
    System.out.println("Look here: "+resource);
  }
```

It reads the `teststring` value fine. But the `testlist` is empty.

Note that I can read the `testlist` fine if it's not wrapped in an Immutables
For example if I changed application.yml to

```
myapp:
  resource:
    teststring: "string"
  testlist:
    - "apple"
    - "banana"
```

and I changed my top-level class to:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class MyAppConfiguration {

  private final ImmutableResourceConfiguration resource;

  public MyAppConfiguration(ImmutableResourceConfiguration resource, List<String> testlist) {
    this.resource = resource.toImmutable();
    System.out.println("Look here: "+testlist);
  }
```

Then `testlist` is correctly populated.

So I'm assuming it has to do with the way the Immutables library processes lists in spring configuration files.

Comment: By the way, while you did apply a tag to your question, there are several library annotations with the simple name `@Immutable`, so it would be helpful to specify the fully-qualified name and possibly link to the library in question. Additionally, the combination of `@Immutable @Modifiable` seems... confusing.

Comment: I added the import statements to be clear about which `@Immutable`. The `@Immutable` tag auto-generates a `ImmutableResourceConfiguration` and the `@Modifiable` tag auto-generates a `ModifiableResourceConfiguration`. It's a little confusing but I need both

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation, I found out that you have to read it as an `String[]` rather than `List<String>`

```
@Immutable
@Modifiable
public abstract class ResourceConfiguration {

  public abstract String[] testlist();

}
```

I don't see this documented anywhere so if anyone can provide that, I will happily select that as the better answer.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit surprised that this works with Immutables `@Immutable` at all, but if `String[]` works, then `List<String>` _ought_ to work, and you should open a ticket against Boot.